# Is it possible to run celery tasks inside of the django runserver when testing?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a django project with several Celery tasks. Also, I have several tests (using django TestCase) and I'm mocking the celery tasks. I don't want to run celery for the tests.

I have searched a lot on the internet, but no luck. So I want to ask: would there be any way not to mock these functions and have the task code executed inside the django runserver?

More info (I can't update them right now):

- python 2.7
- django 1.11
- celery 4.3

Thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`apply`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply) instead of `apply_async` when you call task so that it is executed locally

> `apply(args=None, kwargs=None, link=None, link_error=None, task_id=None, retries=None, throw=None, logfile=None, loglevel=None, headers=None, **options)`
>
> Execute this task locally, by blocking until the task returns.